# How can I filter URLs from appearing in the location bar?

Tags: firefox, address-bar

Whenever I want to open a website I recently visited I get bombarded with duckduckgo.com as suggestions in Firefox's location bar, since the title of websites more often than not have my search terms in them.

Is there a way to exclude duckduckgo.com or any other specific URL/domain from being suggested?

I can forget the page using the history, but that only helps for so long.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the `about:preferences` page and choose the `Search` section on the upper-left.

Once there, uncheck the box for the following option:

```
Show search suggestions in address bar results.
```

[image: Show search suggestions in address bar results]

Comment: I already deactivated this preference. I added a screenshot of what I meant.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but what you want could be a bit problematic.  Your screenshot shows that you only entered *one word* into the address bar, so any URL in your history containing the single word will appear.  Realistically, the way to consistently avoid it would be to temporarily open a `New private window` when you perform a DuckDuckGo search.  That way the results wouldn't appear within your Internet URL history, and you could copy the web page URL that you *do* want to track back into your "normal" Firefox window.